# Routing solver: Unknown Fleet size/ Fleet size optimization/ Infinite fleet size

Tags: optimization, or-tools

I'm trying to solve the CVRPTW with multiple-vehicle types (~42). In my case fleet size/ number of vehicles of each type is unknown. I'm expecting solver to solve for most optimal fleet size and their routes.

Initially I tried to model this problem by creating large number of vehicles for each type and their fixed costs. I expected solver will try to minimize fixed cost of vehicles and distance costs. But in that case solver is unable find an initial solution in significant duration. I think that is because large number of vehicles increases number of possible insertions to a significantly and hence solver fails to explore all possible insertions. i.e: If vehicle type A has 100 vehicles. During insertion phase the solver is trying to insert a job in all 100 vehicles. But since all the empty routes/vehicles are identical we should check insertion cost of all filled vehicles and 1 empty vehicle.

Jsprit library provides an option to define INFINITE fleet size. In this case solver assumes each vehicles type has infinite copy. I think during insertion phase solver tries to add a job in already created routes or 1 empty route of each vehicle type.

**EDIT 1:** I have kept all the jobs (~240) as optional. When I use 10 vehicles of each type (total 420 vehicles) solver returns a solutions with all jobs unassigned after 1 hour. When I reduce number of vehicles of each type to 1(total 42 vehicles), solver returns a feasible solution with 152 unassigned job within 60 seconds.

**EDIT 2**: When I tried to solve it with 1 vehicle type and 200 copies, solver returns a solutions with all jobs unassigned after 1 hour. When I reduce number of vehicles to 60, I get a solution with all jobs assigned within 2 minutes.